# Empty object crashes function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that renders selects to the screen so the user can order data dynamically.

The default states is :

```
    state = {
        sortBy: [ { author: 'asc' } ]
    };
```

the first object above refers to the first row of selects. One select changes object key and the next one object value.

But when I change the first select of the second row the states changes to:

```
state = {
        sortBy: [ { author: 'asc' }, {} ]
    };
```

And crashes my sort function with TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined.

The only way to make it work is by changing first the select that set object value, making the state change to:

```
state = {
        sortBy: [ { author: 'asc' }, {undefined: 'asc'} ]
    };
```

and then change the object key.

Component that renders select to screen:

```
const TYPES = [
    { slug: 'title', description: 'Title' },
    { slug: 'author', description: 'Author' },
    { slug: 'editionYear', description: 'Edition Year' }
];

class BookListSorter extends React.Component {
    state = {
        sortBy: [ { author: 'asc' } ]
    };

    getSortByKeyForIndex = (index) => Object.keys(this.state.sortBy[index] || {})[0];
    getSortByValueForIndex = (index) => Object.values(this.state.sortBy[index] || {})[0];

    changeSort = (key, index) => (e) => {
        const { target } = e;
        this.setState(({ sortBy }) => {
            const type = key === 'type' ? target.value : this.getSortByKeyForIndex(index);
            const direction = key === 'direction' ? target.value : this.getSortByValueForIndex(index);
            return type || direction ? sortBy.splice(index, 1, { [type]: direction }) : sortBy.splice(index, 1);
        });
    };

    filterTypes = (index) => ({ slug }) => {
        const sortByKeys = this.state.sortBy
            .slice(0, index)
            .reduce((keys, sortObj) => keys.concat(Object.keys(sortObj)[0]), []);
        return !sortByKeys.includes(slug);
    };

    render() {
        const { sortBy } = this.state;

        const lastIndex = sortBy.length - 1;
        const shouldAddNewRow = this.getSortByKeyForIndex(lastIndex) && this.getSortByValueForIndex(lastIndex);
        const rowCount = shouldAddNewRow ? sortBy.length + 1 : sortBy.length;

        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Choose sort order</h1>
                {Array.from(Array(Math.min(rowCount, TYPES.length))).map((dummy, index) => (
                    <div>
                        <select
                            defaultValue={this.getSortByKeyForIndex(index)}
                            onChange={this.changeSort('type', index)}
                        >
                            <option value="">None</option>
                            {TYPES.filter(this.filterTypes(index)).map(({ slug, description }) => (
                                <option value={slug}>{description}</option>
                            ))}
                        </select>
                        <select
                            defaultValue={this.getSortByValueForIndex(index)}
                            onChange={this.changeSort('direction', index)}
                        >
                            <option value="asc">None</option>
                            <option value="asc">Ascending</option>
                            <option value="desc">Descending</option>
                        </select>
                        <br />
                    </div>
                ))}
                <br />
                <Books order={sortBy} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Book component that receives BookListSort state as props and use it on order function:

```
class Books extends Component {
    state = {
        order: this.props.order
    };
    componentWillReceiveProps({ order }) {
        this.setState({ ...this.state, order });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>Books</h2>
                <Query query={BOOKS_QUERY}>
                    {({ data, loading, error }) => {
                        if (loading) return <h4>Loading...</h4>;
                        if (error) return <p>Error</p>;

                        // Filter
                        const cleanedSort = this.state.order.filter(
                            (obj) => Object.entries(obj).length !== 0 && obj.constructor === Object
                        );

                        const orderedBooks = orderBooksBy(data.books, cleanedSort);

                        return orderedBooks.map((book) => <Book key={book.id} {...book} />);
                    }}
                </Query>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Order Function:

```
function compareBy(a, b, orderBy) {
    const key = Object.keys(orderBy)[0],
        o = orderBy[key],
        valueA = a[key],
        valueB = b[key];
    if (!(valueA || valueB)) {
        console.error("the objects from the data passed does not have the key '" + key + "' passed on sort!");
        return 0;
    }
    if (+valueA === +valueA) {
        return o.toLowerCase() === 'desc' ? valueB - valueA : valueA - valueB;
    } else {
        if (valueA.localeCompare(valueB) > 0) {
            return o.toLowerCase() === 'desc' ? -1 : 1;
        } else if (valueA.localeCompare(valueB) < 0) {
            return o.toLowerCase() === 'desc' ? 1 : -1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

function orderBooksBy(books, orderBy) {
    orderBy = Array.isArray(orderBy) ? orderBy : [ orderBy ];
    return books.sort((a, b) => {
        let result;
        for (let i = 0; i < orderBy.length; i++) {
            result = compareBy(a, b, orderBy[i]);
            if (result !== 0) {
                return result;
            }
        }
        return result;
    });
}

export default orderBooksBy;
```

Comment: can you show your `orderBooksBy` function and the part of code where you add the your filter to the state ?

Comment: your isEmpty fn is backwards it seems.

Comment: I have update my questions with the code. I also edit with the filter function suggested bellow

Answer (score 2):

I would resolve it with a filter.
When retrieving sortBy array you can do the following:

```js
// State
state = {
  sortBy: [ { author: 'asc' }, {} ]
};

// Filter
const cleanedSort = this.state.sortBy.filter(obj => Object.entries(obj).length !== 0 && obj.constructor === Object);

// Get it cleaned
console.log(cleanedSort);
```

Comment: This would cause issues with more than two rows, since it's not storing a relative index. At least, I was under the impression the number of rows was variable - but maybe it's not... @asotos

Comment: I have tried that but unfortunately is still with the same error. I'll edit my code below